# Fastest Route Optimization

Tags: derivatives, optimization

I am currently doing optimization and I am quite unfamiliar with the whole concept of how to answer questions for different parts. I was wondering if somebody would help me understand.

Point A and is on the left and Point B is on the righthand side 26 km North. A person at Point A needs to cross to the opposite side. Which is 12 km wide and east from Point A. If he plans properly, he can leave his car at any point on the other side to go to Point B. With his boat, he can sail at the speed of 16km/h. While with the car he can travel at 30km/h. We will assume that the sides are two parallel lines and that he can cross-strait by boat from Point A directly to any point on the other side, where he will take his car to drive up to Point B. 
Model the travelling path both by boat and car to get from Point A to Point B. 
What is the actual distance from Point 2 where he needs to land with the boat to minimize his time? What is the minimal time spent on travel from Point A to Point B? What is the length of the crossing path on water?

Comment: Please show your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults) to know how to ask a good question on this website. (Please take note that this website does **not** do your homework for you)

Comment: Monica try drawing the figure. Then try expressing all the quantities in terms of a single variable $x$. If you add these details to your question I am sure you will get an answer lot faster and it will also help you understand the soln.